# Как исппользовать layout_weight, когда есть только один элемент (вопрос об относительной разметке)

Tags: android, android-layout

Добрый день. Есть размета

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    myapp:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_weight="9" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="OK" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Отмена" />
</LinearLayout>
```

На этой разметке используется layout_weight для разделения экрана в отношении 90% (картинка) и 10% (панель с кнопками). Я использую layout_weight, как подобие процентных величин в css

Как сделать так, чтобы под панель с кнопками все так же выделялось 10% от высоты экрана, но при этом чтобы ImageView не присутствовал на макете (если его убрать из разметки выше, то панель с кнопками займет весь экран)?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Зачем мне это нужно**: Я хочу сверстать вот такой вот **элемент** для своего списка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне кажется, что это дело делается так: картинка растягивается по ширине и высоте экрана (не забываем, что верстаем только **ЭЛЕМЕНТ** из списка), снизу добавляется FrameLayout, в котором в качестве параметра background задается прозрачная картинка. А потом на FrameLayout помещается TextView

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я не хочу задавать высоту FrameLayout в конкретных числах, потому что как мне кажется, это повлияет на внешний вид приложения на маленьком экране. А способ, который я использовал в самом начале не подходит, т.к. картинка отображается и **под FrameLayout**. Как мне задать в процентах высоту FrameLayout, когда над ним нет элемента? И что вы вообще думаете о таком подходе? Я дизайне и создании макетов новичок, так что буду рад услышать ваши замечания и советы.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Ваша задача сверстать разметку для элемента списка, аналогичную скриншоту с суши?

Comment: Да, именно! Я никогда еще не занимался разметкой без мануалов, поэтому и решил посоветоваться с ru-OS как лучше сделать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлагаю слишком не мудрить и использовать такую разметку:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="4dp">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/sushi" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@color/backgraundAlpha"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:text="Loren Ipsum" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

файл res/values/colors.xml:

```
<resources>

    <color name="backgraundAlpha">#50000000</color>
</resources>
```

`ImageView` занимает всю доступную ширину и необходимое место по высоте с заполнением CenterCrop и определяет собой размер родительского контейнера (его высота `wrap_content`).
`TextView` привязывается нижним краем к нижнему краю контейнера и имеет полупрозрачный бэкграунд и паддинги для увеличения высоты.  Они будут не именно 10%, но всегда гармонично смотрется с текстом. Конкретное значение (у меня *20dp*) вы можете подобрать сами.

Вместо `TextView` можно использовать горизонтальный `LinearLayout`, например, если требуется в нижней части раположить несколько элементов

Вот что получается в итоге:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо вам большое за развернутый ответ. Пока возьму ваш пример и попробую определить, подходит ли он под мои нужды.

Comment: Да, ваш подход идеально подошел. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Для относительной вёрстки в процентах отлично подходит библиотека `Android support percent` от Google. Пример работы с ней можно найти на [habrahabr.ru](https://habrahabr.ru/post/308152/)

Comment: Просто факт того, что подобный функционал вынесен в отдельную библиотеку заставляет меня думать, что существуют более предпочтительные способы верстки, чем при помощи процентов. Такое чувство, что эта библиотека выпущена специально для таких как я которые не осилили другие приемы верстки.

Comment: @RareScrap проследив логику создания их библиотек, можно понять, что создаются они, чаще всего, в тех случаях, когда конкретный функционал упрощает разработку, но нужен далеко не каждому. Обычное модулирование решений. Если вас смущает `Android support percent`, как вариант можно посмотреть в сторону `ConstraintLayout`.

Comment: ... который тоже внешняя библиотека поддержки :)

Comment: Окей, понял. Но что вы двое думаете о том, как лучше решить такую задачу? Использовать Android support percent, ConstraintLayout или возиться с layout_weight?

Comment: @RareScrap можно у родительского `Layout` установить `android:weightSum="10"` и посмотреть на результат. Если он не устроит  - я вы использовал `percent`.

Comment: @RareScrap библиотеки поддержки разрабатываются не для неудачников верстки или программирования, а из желания разработчиков платформы предоставить удобные инструменты для уже выпущенных API, а не только в последнее. То есть, например ConstraintLayout появился в этом году и разработчики могли просто включить его а текущее API 24 и использовать этот замечательный инструмент вы могли бы только в приложениях с минимальной версией Android 6.0, вместо этого они сделали библиотеку поддержки и теперь вы используете этот контейнер для приложений от Android 4.0

Answer (score 1):

Я конечно извиняюсь за такой варварский подход но почему бы просто не заменить ImageView на space чтобы не заморачиваться с сторонними библиотеками и не сталкиваться с вытекающими из них проблемами. space легковесный элемент разметки предназначенный для заполнения пустого пространства в случаях вроде вашего.

<
android.support.v4.widget.Space

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="9" />
```

Comment: Я тоже думал не заморачиваться и использовать элемент-заполнитель, но не знал что такой элемент уже есть. Спасибо, теперь буду знать про Space