# Вёрстка динамического фрагмента

Tags: android, android-fragment

Доброго времени суток! Делаю вёрстку динамического  каталога с помощью адаптеров.
Приложение будет отлавливать JSON с данными и впихивать их в 3 фрагмента.
Сложность именно в динамическом создании блока (картинка + заголовок).
Спасибо за быстрый ответ!

UPD:
Если у меня будет всего 3 блока (картинка + заголвок), то как их динамически расположить и с помощью какого макета?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я так понимаю, вам нужно реализовать список через `GridLayoutManager` и `RecyclerView`, например, и организовать бесконечную подгрузку данных. Поищите "endless recyclerview scrolling"  или "infinity recyclerview scrolling"... Ну например: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews-and-RecyclerView

Comment: В случае `RecyclerView`, ваши картинка+заголовок будут одним `ViewHolder`.

Comment: Если, конечно, вы не про iOS спрашиваете, судя по скриншотам :)

Comment: насчет именно верстки может [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/643267/177345) чем то поможет или ввм не айтем сверстать надо, а относительное расположение айтемов в списке? Насчет второго вопроса - один вопрос может содержать только одну проблему, если у вас несколько проблем - создайте несколько вопросов

Comment: Спасибо за быстрый ответ.
Мне нужно сделать именно такой макет (cat3(левый нижний), android разумеется), и я не понимаю как расположить блоки.
Если у меня будет всего 1 или 3 блока как их поставить именно в таком положении? По бесконечной загрузки примерно понял.

Comment: Если у вас заранее известно число элементов, используйте `GridLayout` (как можно это сделать: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=go9q4O44b4E). Если у вас элементы появляются динамически и их довольно много может быть, используйте `RecyclerView` + `GridLayoutManager`. Вам не нужно беспокоиться сколько у вас элементов (0,1, 2, 3 ... ) - хотя для каких-либо  целей это можно отлавливать -  `GridLayoutManager` распределит элементы самостоятельно (хотя и это можно настроить).

Comment: Смотрите пример: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40587168/simple-android-grid-example-using-recyclerview-with-gridlayoutmanager-like-the Вам нужно будет задать число столбцов в в конструкции `recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, numberOfColumns));` В вашем случае `numberOfColumns` = 2

Comment: @AlexKisel Спасибо за пример! Завтра изучу