# TextView поверх ImageView

Tags: android

Как сделать так, чтобы `TextView` был поверх `ImageView`? Делаю так, но `TextView` оказывается в конце, а `ImageView` по центру. Как сделать, чтобы получилось так как на картинке?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="#FFF">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/no_image" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#7000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Название блюда"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/643267/177345

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал так.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:background="#FFF">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/no_image" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imgIcon"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:background="#7000"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:text="Название блюда"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно разместить ваш imageView и textView в framelayout:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true">

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:lines="1" />

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/menu_icon_margin_top_bottom"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/menu_icon_margin_right"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/menu_icon_margin_top_bottom" />
</FrameLayout>
```

или попробовать добавить строку в вашем textView:

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

Comment: Немного по другому сделал. Но спасибо за ответ.